# Apollo how to provide meanful __typenames?

Tags: graph, apollo-client, hasura

I have a setup of Hasura -> Apollo -> React.
Apollo adds `__typename`s automatically to all results. They should be good meanful names like Artist or Book, or something.
In my case they are all `Query`
Hasura generates the grapql schema itself, so that part should be covered. Where should I dig?
Here is an example of the implementation:

```js
export const FETCH_FOLLOWED_ARTIST = gql`
  query FetchFollowedArtist($uuid: uuid!, $artist_id: String!) {
    users_performers_by_pk(user_id: $uuid, artist_id: $artist_id) {
      user_id
      artist_id
    }
  }
`;
```

where user_performers is a simple table of two fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given GraphQL selection set, `__typename` should be the table, except for root, where by default `__typename` is `query_root` for queries and `mutation_root` for mutations.

For example, I have a table called "user". Given this query:

```
query {
  __typename
  user {
    __typename
  }
}
```

the result is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "__typename": "query_root",
    "user": [
      {
        "__typename": "user"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you add `__typename` to your example:

```
export const FETCH_FOLLOWED_ARTIST = gql`
  query FetchFollowedArtist($uuid: uuid!, $artist_id: String!) {
    __typename # <- added this
    users_performers_by_pk(user_id: $uuid, artist_id: $artist_id) {
      __typename # <- added this
      user_id
      artist_id
    }
  }
`;
```

you should see something similar, definitely not `Query` for both values.

> Where should I dig?

For a given table, under "Modify", you can change root fields:

[image]

But for queries, `__typename` always returns the name of the table.

Comment: This is correct. After playing with Hasura console and checking the Apollo cache, I indeed see everything I need.